# Как производится оценка функции по памяти?

Tags: c++, сложность

К примеру, имеется у меня некоторая функция А()

```
void А(vector<int> in){
vector<int> temp;
int k=0;
for(auto i : in) 
    if (n[i]%2==0){
        temp.push_back(n[i]); k++; 
     }
}
```

Предположим, что in.size() - четный.
Правильно ли я понимаю, что оценка по памяти O(in.size() + in.size()/2) ?

Comment: O(n + n/2) == O(n)

Comment: @Harry да, это я понимаю, не сократил до конца:) переменные, которые создаются в оценке не учитываются? И как быть в случае, если бы я использовал std::sort(in.begin(),in.end()), влияет ли это на оценку?

Comment: Надо смотреть, какие требования по памяти у сортировки. насколько я помню, `std::sort`сортирует на месте, так что дополнительно ему нужно O(1).